# Demodulating ISO14443 (part of NFC) using SDR?

Tags: software-defined-radio, rtl-sdr

I'm looking for info on demodulating both sides of an ISO14443 communication using a cheap SDR, preferably an RTL-SDR (R820T2+RTL2832U). The application is passively monitoring an [NFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-field_communication) exchange for debugging purposes (like [this](https://github.com/Proxmark/proxmark3/wiki) or [this](http://www.keolabs.com/SC-ProxiSPY__product__smart-card-testing.html) specialized tools allow), using a pickup coil next to the devices. I'm restricting to ISO/IEC 14443-2:2010 (which covers some of the most-used NFC modes).

Operation uses magnetic induction at f<sub>c</sub>=13.56MHz (an ISM band). The field is generated by the reader (aka PCD), with a TRP often up to 1W. It is picked-up by a card (aka PICC) at like up to 100mm. The PICC's antenna is typically a coil (like 60mm diameter, 3 turns), connected to an (integrated) capacitor forming an L(R)C tuned slightly above f<sub>c</sub>, followed by a rectifier for power extraction. The PICC transmits by load modulation of a sub-carrier at f<sub>s</sub>=f<sub>c</sub>/16=847.5kHz. That creates sidebands (e.g. at f<sub>c</sub>±f<sub>s</sub>).

PCD transmission is ASK ≈10% NRZ-L (or [*] ASK ≈100% modified Miller). PICC transmission is BPSK NRZ-L (or [*] OOK Manchester). Bit rates are f<sub>s</sub>/8, f<sub>s</sub>/4, f<sub>s</sub>/2, sometime f<sub>s</sub> (≈106, 212, 424, sometime 848 kbit/s), negotiated independently in each direction.
[*] These modes are for the so-called "type A" at f<sub>s</sub>/8 bit rate.

Issues designing a circuit between the pickup coil and SDR:

- the 13.56MHz field can be strong (>4V RMS for each turn of an unloaded 60mm diameter pickup coil) and should not fry the SDR
- that 13.56MHz field varies enormously (?-25dB) depending PCD, PICC, and position of a pickup coil (and to a lesser degree according to internal activity in the PICC, which varies between communication bursts).
- the 847.5kHz sub-carrier is comparatively very weak (?-40dB), and also very variable depending on devices and placement of a pickup coil.

Info, links, ideas (even half-baked) welcome.

Answer (score 4):

This isn’t a solution to your problem, but I had similar challenges with UHF RFID  at 865 MHz. In UHF RFID the tags are electrically short dipoles modulated by the chip impedance.  I thought it would be impossible to measure the two way traffic due to the huge difference in the TX and RX signal amplitudes.

I solved this by making a tiny hole through the tag antenna matching loop near the chip. I then looped a single wire through the hole and connected this loop to the coax going to the RTL-SDR. The loop acts as a transformer or current sensing probe. Because I measure the current through the tag chip and both RX and TX are binary AM (almost CW), both signals have almost the same amplitude.

I never did the actual demodulation, but I used the SDR# to save the signal and then Python to plot the amplitude in time domain.

Answer (score 2):

Check my project at https://github.com/josevcm/nfc-laboratory

Regards
Jv

Comment: Hello Jose Vicente, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Ordinarily we frown upon one-line answers that are just links, but since your link goes to a GitHub code repository with code that does exactly what the question is asking for, or something close to it, I think in this case a one-line answer with a link is entirely appropriate.  Thanks Jose Vicente!